# nodejs and mongoose return undefined when logging json data

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a function to return json data from a mongoose table.It first insert a newpost and then retrive the same post by the post._id.

```
   dbConfig.newPost(post,id,function (err,post) {
         if(err) throw(err);
         dbConfig.getPostById(post._id,function (err,doc) {
            if(err) throw err;
            var data = JSON.stringify(doc);
             console.log(data);
             console.log(data._id);
         });

     });
```

The query prints the data variable as a array of objects in JSON but when i try to only print the 'data._id' it returns undefined. Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong? An snip of the json array is below

```
[{"_id":"593ab877777ae318e4a35637","userPost":"savassge","_creator":{"_id":"592b8c2d0c28f01970ad4df7","username":"adrian"},"__v":0,"dateCreated":"2017-06-09T15:02:15.716Z"}]
```

Comment: Try -- `console.log(data[0]._id);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly

`var data` is a string, not an object nor an array as you are assigning the return value of `JSON.stringify(doc)` to your `data` variable. The JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Secondly

You are trying to access a non existent property of your `doc` array, this property as you illustrated in your question exists in each object within your array. In order to print the `_id` property of each object (assuming that's what you would like to do), you'll need to iterate over the array first:

```
dbConfig.newPost(post, id, function (err, post) {
  if(err) throw(err);
  dbConfig.getPostById(post._id, function(err, data) {
    if(err) throw err;
    data.forEach(function(doc) {
      console.log(doc);
      console.log(doc._id);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks much but my problem was that i used find() to retrieve the document instead of findOne() which cause it to return a array of objects

Answer (score 0):

Because there's no "data._id". There is "data[0]._id". You are trying to access an array of objects, not an object.

Comment: thanks much that helped me to find the real problem. I was using the find method which return arrays of object which didn't exists. I used findOne which only return a single document.